# ExtJS 4 password validation

Tags: javascript, extjs, passwords, extjs4

I'm using these 2 blocks of code in order to validate a password field. When the password in the confirm field is not equal to the first field, the textbox is marked red so the user knows that the passwords are not equal.

Now, the thing i want to accomplish:
I want to disable the navigation buttons of my form whenever the passwords are not equal.
I've tried with the clientvalidation event but this is only triggered if you submit your form (which i'm not doing).

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {
    password : function(val, field) {
        if (field.initialPassField) {
           var pwd = Ext.getCmp(field.initialPassField);
           return (val == pwd.getValue());
        }
        return true;
     },
    passwordText : 'Enter 2 times the same password!'
});
```

Example:

```
access.push({
fieldLabel: 'Password',
anchor: '99%',
name: 'passwd',
id: 'passwd',
inputType: 'password',
maxLength: 40,
vtype: 'password'
});

access.push({
fieldLabel: 'Password again',
name: 'passwd1',
id: 'passwd1',
maxLength: 40,
inputType: 'password',
vtype: 'password',
initialPassField: 'passwd'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to the button you want to disable property `bindForm: true`. It will make button enabled/disabled based on the form's validity.

Comment: This would work if the button would be on the same panel but in my case it is not. My application is a wizardscreen with a bottombar which holds my nav buttons. It would be ideal if I could catch the event when the confirm password is not correct so I could disable the nav button from there...

Comment: You have the validation function - what else do you need? Catch it from there